# SQL schema / query design for horizontally scaled clients iterating through a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables (simplified)

```
List_To_Action
----------------------------------------------------
| Item_Name | Date_Time_Actioned | Action_Success? |
----------------------------------------------------
```

And

```
Action_Records (created by software)
------------------------------------------------
| ID | Item_Name | Date | ... | Action_Success?|
------------------------------------------------
```

I'm writing a python script that tells a client to iterate through List_To_Action for items that have not yet been actioned.

This would be simple if I had just one client accessing the table:

```
SELECT * FROM List_To_Action WHERE Date_Time_Actioned IS NULL
```

However, I will be horizontally scaling and multiple clients will be hitting this list to search for items that have not been actioned, so what I want to know is.

How would I set up the schema / query for this list so that when multiple clients are hitting List_To_Action, they're not pulling out the same items? Pseudo code / pointers are fine.

Comment: I don't think you can lock it on `SELECT`, it should be locked on `UPDATE`. If you are doing update from application make sure you do it in transaction and add `WHERE Date_Time_Actioned IS NULL` on update query so that second try of update will fail

Comment: @mirko - cool that gives me at least something to go off, I'll admit my sql knowledge is pretty poor.